# Luaotfload package

Tags: luaotfload

I need a simple example regarding the use of the Luaotfload package, what are its uses how can it be used regarding Unicode fonts in latex (lualatex + Babel). Can it be used to color fonts, what aspects does it manipulate and what advantages does it offer?

Comment: See the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/luaotfload-latex.pdf), page 12 is about colors.

Comment: So when to use this package for coloring and when it is better to use LUACOLOR package?

Comment: As soon as you are using lualatex you are using luaotfload. It is the core code to handle fonts. Check your log-file, you will find lots of lines from luaotfload. E.g `Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02`

Comment: As you are interested in babel + lualatex, you can find sample files in https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/samples . Some of them are simple, others are not.